# Was there a chance that Thanos would die too?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

When Thanos snaps his fingers at the end of the Avengers movie, half of the population of the universe wipes out.

Since Thanos is included in the Universe population, could there be a chance that he would die too?

Comment: [Cross site related.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186933/who-decides-which-half-of-the-universe-should-be-destroyed)

Comment: Tried to reduce the spoiler-ness of the title.  Yes, it still talks about "chance" but its less obvious to comic book fans that it means that Thanos achieves his goal.

Comment: What makes you think Thanos is alive?