# Was Thanos part of the possible 50% that he want to kill?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

So, Thanos's goal was to bring balance to the Universe by eradicating 50% of the living.  I wonder, was he part of the general population that could have died?  In other words, but killing half the living, was he not likely to kill himself as well?

Comment: [Was there a chance that Thanos would die too?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88638/was-there-a-chance-that-thanos-would-die-too)

Comment: I would think Thanos would be subject to the same outcome as everyone else. Perhaps Thanos created 2 duplicate universes and killed 50% of everyone in Universe A and killed the other 50% in Universe B. Everyone dies, everyone lives, and Thanos has a 100% chance of surviving while achieving his goal.